# keep getting " see declaration of 'class " error

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have my code written but keep getting the following when I try and run it:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project 2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Project 2.cpp
1>c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\account.h(6): error C2011: 'account' : 'class' type redefinition
1>          c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\account.h(6) : see declaration of 'account'
1>c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\checking.h(9): error C2504: 'account' : base class undefined
1>c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\creditcard.h(9): error C2504: 'account' : base class undefined
1>c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\saving.h(9): error C2504: 'account' : base class undefined
1>c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\project 2.cpp(45): error C2039: 'makeDeposit' : is not a member of 'saving'
1>          c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\saving.h(8) : see declaration of 'saving'
1>c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\project 2.cpp(59): error C2039: 'makeDeposit' : is not a member of 'checking'
1>          c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\checking.h(8) : see declaration of 'checking'
1>  Account.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
1>  Saving.cpp
1>  CreditCard.cpp
1>  Checking.cpp
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am not sure what any of these errors are or what I am doing wrong...

Here is my Main():

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "Account.h"
#include "Checking.h"
#include "CreditCard.h"
#include "Saving.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    saving sa;
    creditCard cca;
    checking ca;

    string n;
    int option;
    int exit = 1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Checking Balance:" << " " << "          " << "Savings balance:" << " " << "          " << "Credit Card balance:" << " " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << " (1) Savings Deposit " << endl;
    cout << " (2) Savings withdrawel " << endl;
    cout << " (3) Checking Deposit " << endl;
    cout << " (4) Write A Check " << endl;
    cout << " (5) Credit Card Payment " << endl;
    cout << " (6) Make A Charge " << endl;
    cout << " (7) Display Savings " << endl;
    cout << " (8) Display Checkings " << endl;
    cout << " (9) Display Credit Card " << endl;
    cout << " (0) Exit " << endl;
    cin >> option;

    do{

    switch ( option )

    {
        case 1 : {
                 double SamtD;
                 cout << " Please enter how much you would like to deposit into savings " << endl;
                 cin >> SamtD;
                 sa.makeDeposit(SamtD);
                 break;
                 }
        case 2 : {
                 double SamtW;
                 cout << " Please enter how much you would like to withdrawel "<< endl;
                 cin >> SamtW;
                 sa.doWithdraw(SamtW);
                 break;
                 }
        case 3 : {
                 double CamtD;
                 cout << " Please enter how much you would like to deposit into checkings " << endl;
                 cin >> CamtD;
                 ca.makeDeposit(CamtD);
                 break;
                 }
        case 4 : {
                 double CamtW;
                 int chkNum;
                 cout << " Please enter how much you wrote on the check " << endl;
                 cin >> CamtW;
                 cout << " Please enter the check number " << endl;
                 cin >> chkNum;
                 ca.writeCheck(chkNum, CamtW);
                 break;
                 }
        case 5 : {
                 double CCmkP;
                 cout << " Please enter the amount you would like to deposit " << endl;
                 cin >> CCmkP;
                 cca.makePayment(CCmkP);
                 break;
                 }
        case 6 : {
                 double DoC;
                 string Nm;
                 cout << " Please enter the amount charged to your credit card " << endl;
                 cin >> DoC;
                 cout << " Please enter where the charge was made " << endl;
                 getline(cin, Nm);
                 cca.doCharge(Nm,DoC);
                 break;
                 }
        case 7 : {
                 sa.display();
                 break;
                 }
        case 8 : {
                 ca.display();
                 break;
                 }
        case 9 : {
                 cca.display();
                 break;
                 }
        case 0 : exit = 0;
                 break;
        default : exit = 0;
                 cout << " ERROR ";
    }
    }
    while(exit==1);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the class saving.h(very similar to checking and creditcard so I assume they are related issues :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class saving: public account
{
public :

    double doWithdraw(double amount);
    string display();
    saving();
    saving(string itsName, long itsTaxID, double itsBalance);
};
```

This is the .cpp file for saving :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "Saving.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

saving::saving():account()
{
}

saving::saving(string itsName, long itsTaxID, double itsBalance): account(itsName, itsTaxID, itsBalance)
{
}

double saving:: doWithdraw(double amount)
{
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the base class account.h. saving checking and creditcard inherit from this class :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
class account {

public :
    void setName(string name); void setTaxID(long taxID); void setBalance(double balance);
    string getName(); long getTaxID(); double getBalance();
    double makeDeposit( double amount );
    account();
    account(string itsName, long itsTaxID, double itsBalance);
    int display();

private :
    string itsName;
    long itsTaxID;
    double itsBalance;

protected :
    double last10withdraws[10];
    double last10deposits[10];
    int numdeposits;
    int numwithdraws;

};
```

and the account.cpp :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

account::account():itsName(""), itsTaxID(0), itsBalance(0)
{
}

account::account(string itsName, long itsTaxID, double itsBalance): itsName(), itsTaxID(), itsBalance()
{
}

void account::setName(string name)
{
    itsName = name;
}

string account::getName()
{
    return itsName;
}

void account::setTaxID(long taxID)
{
    itsTaxID = taxID;
}

long account::getTaxID()
{
    return itsTaxID;
}

void account::setBalance(double balance)
{
    balance = 100;
    itsBalance = balance;
}

double account::getBalance()
{
    return itsBalance;
}

double account::makeDeposit( double amount )
{
    return amount;
}

int account::display()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea why I keep getting these errors? It just makes no sense to me .

Comment: The `see declaration` line isn't itself an error; it's a note to help you fix the error on the previous line, `'class' type redefinition`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep getting the errors because the header files are included more than once. This causes the compiler to attempt compiling the classes more than once. Since the class has already been declared you can't do it again. To solve this problem you need to use header guards *placed in your header file*.

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H // <--- first line of your header file.
#define FILENAME_H


// Place your header file contents here


#endif // <--- last line of your header file.
```

`FILENAME_H` typically matches the filename of the header file.

As a side note, remove `#include "stdafx.h"` from your header files. It only belongs in .cpp files and then **only** as the very first `#include`. For example your account.h file would look like this

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H

#include "iostream"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
class account {

public :
    void setName(string name); void setTaxID(long taxID); void setBalance(double balance);
    string getName(); long getTaxID(); double getBalance();
    double makeDeposit( double amount );
    account();
    account(string itsName, long itsTaxID, double itsBalance);
    int display();

private :
    string itsName;
    long itsTaxID;
    double itsBalance;

protected :
    double last10withdraws[10];
    double last10deposits[10];
    int numdeposits;
    int numwithdraws;

};

#endif
```

Comment: would I use these header guards in all my .cpp and .h or just my main?

Comment: In the header files. I've updated my answer to clarify that. Oops.

Comment: Thank you Captain Obvious. I did this and now I am getting this error under each of my .cpp files....:

Comment: 1>c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\checking.h(1): warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline
1>c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\checking.h(2): error C2008: '.' : unexpected in macro definition
1>c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\account.h(1): warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline
1>c:\users\geena\desktop\zaks stuff\project 2\project 2\project 2\account.h(2): error C2008: '.' : unexpected in macro definition

Comment: Then something is wrong on line two. I have no idea what because I don't know what you typed there. I've provided an example of what your account.h file should look like.

Answer (score 0):

I think the header files are being included more than once. 
just add `#pragma once` as first line in every header file.

Comment: I went ahead and added #pragma once into all four .h files. It got rid of all the errors but now I have four of these:

Comment: 1>Project 2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall creditCard::display(void)" (?display@creditCard@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)

Comment: @ZachKenny You declared `creditCard::display()` but didn't provide an implementation for it.

Comment: O alright Thank you. Hopefully that works. Man does your name make me feel like an idiot.